# How to prevent fragments from being recreated when using BottomNavigationView with Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I have an app, one activity, with BottomNavigationView and Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And four fragments, I navigate like this, in MainActivity:

```
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        binding.navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_fra1 -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main).navigate(R.id.Fragment)
                }
                R.id.navigation_fra2 -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main).navigate(R.id.Fragment2)
                }
                R.id.navigation_fra3 -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main).navigate(R.id.Fragment3)
                }
                R.id.navigation_fra4 -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main).navigate(R.id.Fragment4)
                }
            }
            true
        }
```

Fragments are all the same but pull different data from Firebase Database:

```
class Fragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var arrayList: ArrayList<FireItems>
 
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
   
        arrayList = ArrayList()

        val database = Firebase.database
        val myRef = database.getReference("items")
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val value = dataSnapshot.value
                arrayList.clear()
                Log.d("mDatabase", "Value is: $value")
                for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {

                    arrayList.add(FireItems(postSnapshot.child("image").value.toString(), postSnapshot.child("name").value.toString(), postSnapshot.child("description").value.toString()))
                    if (!arrayList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        binding.apply {
                            progressCircular.visibility = View.GONE
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
                            val adapter = FireRecyclerViewAdapter(requireActivity(), arrayList)
                            recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 2)
                            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("mDatabase", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        })

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {}
        })

        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

I need to make it so that when I move from one fragment to another through the BottomNavigationView, fragments are not recreated each time. Because, firstly, if there are a lot of elements in the list, I don’t want to have to scroll through the entire recycler every time, and secondly, pulling the database every time is not correct as far as I know.
Please tell me how to do it better?

Comment: Since Navigation 2.4.0, Navigation will keep the state of each item when you reselect that tab, but you are specifically throwing out that behavior by setting your own `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` that calls `navigate()` to go to a brand new instance. Why are you doing that at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Even if I create a project through google template with 

`val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)`

fragments still recreted(

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am getting issue like him ?
I have checked, the fragment is being destroyed (not just destroyedView). And then back to bottom item, the new fragment is created

Comment: @ThânHoàng Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @JarinRocks Unfortunately no

Comment: try this https://blog.mindorks.com/saving-fragment-states-with-bottomnvaigationview @Binary

Comment: Didn't you find any solution still?

Comment: For some guys who still finding the solution for it.
There is no way to prevent fragment's view is being destroyed since the mechanism of navigation component. It will always destroy the view and restore the state once the fragment is back.

The thing we need to ensure when applying the fragmentContainer with bottomNavigationBar is:
```
1. Ensure the data need to retained is kept in ViewModel
2. Ensure the views in the fragment layout has the ID. This very important since the fragment is saving the state by copying the state with view ID and trying to bundle it to save and restore.
```